# I want both key and value from JSON object

Tags: java, json, key-value

The JSON object

```
"Stores create/update": [
  {
    "id": 780,
    "callback": "Stores create/update",
    "date": "2021-10-07"
    
  }]
```

I want string `"id :780"`- without using  `jsonobject.get("id");`

Comment: What have you done so far? Add some code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can just concatenate the key with value, so getting value is enough, also parse the JSON into object first.

```
// do something to get value (not sure if this is syntax for java)
value = jsonObject[0].id
// then just concat value
ansString = "id :"+ value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var js1 = {"Stores create/update": [
      {
        "id": 780,
        "callback": "Stores create/update",
        "date": "2021-10-07"

      }]};
    console.log(JSON.stringify(js1).replace(/.*:\s?(\d{1,}).*/, '"id :$1"'));
  </script>
```